# Including graphics into a savequote

Tags: graphics, floats, quotchap

I use `quotchap` for each chapter of a book.
For a specific chapter, I would like to replace the text by a picture (`.jpg`).

Unfortunately, the `\begin{figure}` directive does not seem to work inside a `\begin{savequote}` environment.
Is there a workaround I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use the `figure` environment in order to include images. You should only use

```
\begin{savequote}
  %...
  \includegraphics[<opts>]{<file>}% your image
  %...
\end{savequote}
```

and the image will be inserted (where you specify the `<file>` with some `<opts>`).